# QTimer, QThread, and TCP messaging

Tags: qthread

Qt 4.8, Windows XP:

I have a thread that manages my TCP messages and opens / maintains / closes the socket at the appropriate times.

This same thread starts a QTimer, 200 ms, defined in my thread's data, that pumps an event in my thread's class once (if) the socket is open. So the timer and its event belong to the thread, as best I understand the idea.

The QTimer timeout event sends a TCP message through the port belonging to the thread, it's a keep-alive message for this particular hardware item. Has to be sent regularly or the device "goes away" which won't do.

When the message is sent, I get this error:

"QSocketNotifier: socket notifiers cannot be enabled from another thread"

As far as I can tell, I *am* sending the message from the same thread and would expect any signals, etc., to be owned / handled etc. by it.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

PS: The message *is* sent, the device *does* stay alive... it's just that I'm getting this runtime error on the Qt error console and I'm very concerned that there are internal problems lurking because of it.

The message does NOT occur running under OS X 10.6. I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here's the scoop. QTimer, for reason only known to the designers of QT,  inherits the context of the parent of the thread. Not the context of the thread it's launched from. So when the timer goes off, and you send a message from the slot it called, you're not in the thread's context, you're in the parents context.

You also can't launch a thread that is child of THAT thread, so that you can fire a timer that will actually be in the thread you want. Qt won't let it run.

So, spend some memory, make a queue, load the message into the queue from elsewhere, watch the queue in the thread that owns the TCP port, and send em when ya got em. That works.

Comment: +1 This answer might have saved my job, no kidding! Could you tell me if this still holds in Qt5? And, also, could you please elaborate on where in the documentation this is described? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I have found that QTimer does not inherit the cotext of the parent of the thread in Qt5 ( I don't know about Qt4.x). But you have to make sure that the QTimer is moved along with the worker object by making it a child of the worker or creating it in the new context. See this useful post: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/21141